# Bad syntax highlighting for single quotes in Lisp

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighter doesn't work properly when single quote is used in Lisp family languages. It treats it like a surrounding quote, highlighting all the code until the next single quote as a string, but it's a prefix operator in Lisp. Lisp only uses double quote for strings.

See [Recur not at tail position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945995/recur-not-at-tail-position) for example. The 3 lines beginning with the `(doseq` line should not be highlighted.

I tried adding an explicit language highlighting comment:

```
<!-- language: lang-lisp -->
```

before the code block, but it didn't help.

Comment: The syntax highlighting for lisp itself seems to be correct. If you use `<!-- language: lang-lisp -->` it's processed as lisp code. Looks like the tag `lisp` does not trigger the right syntax highlighter.

Comment: Maybe it's caused by one of the other tags... Clojure?

Comment: @Floern I tried adding a `<!-- language` comment to override the tags, it didn't help. See the editing history.

Comment: @Barmar make sure you have a blank line between the `<!-- -->` and the code block.

Comment: Ahh, that was my mistake. Someone else has since edited it correctly.

Comment: Oops, I see that was you. :)

Comment: So it sounds like maybe the problem is just that `lisp` and/or `clojure` tags aren't triggering the Lisp syntax highlighter.

Comment: [tag:clojure] has a different syntax highlighter than [tag:lisp] (namely `lang-clj`), which was picked by default because of the tag order

Comment: @m0sa Shouldn't clojure have lisp-style highlighting for single quotes?

Comment: no clue, if it should, and it doesn't, [this is the place](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues) to [report a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/156631)